# Options for transferring file to iPhone/iPad

Tags: iphone, ipad

I'm working on an app and need to add the ability to import CSV files into the app for processing.  What are the options here?  I've read posts about embedding http servers or fetching a CSV file from a web resource, but what is the easiest way to do this?

thanks

Comment: Can you clarify what you want?

Answer (score 0):

I've used NSData's **dataWithContentsOfURL:** just recently; it worked fine. Plus there's a convenient **writeToFile:atomically:** or **writeToFile:options:error:** message you can send to your data object.